# How verification of a "google sign-in" JWT works

Tags: authentication, jwt, google-signin, impersonation, verification

I am trying to understand how the JWT sent from Google to the client when using the sign in with Google feature, can be verified on my server for authentication.

I would like to authenticate a user with a specific email on my server.

Here's the flow as I perceive it:

1. User clicks "Sign in with Google."
2. Client obtains a JWT from the Google API.
3. Client forwards the JWT to my server.
4. Server verifies the token using Google's provided client library.
5. I validate if the email is "allowed@email.com."
6. If it's the whitelisted email, I issue a cookie granting access to protected APIs.

However, I'm curious about the potential for JWT manipulation. Is it feasible for someone to tamper with a JWT and send it to my server, claiming the email "allowed@email.com" without actual access to that email, thereby gaining access to protected APIs?

How can I ensure that the user claiming ownership of the email actually owns it?

Does the verification method of the client library, such as GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync in the Google client for .NET, handle this aspect of security?

I have managed to receive JWT on my server but fail to understand how it is to be trusted.

Comment: "*How can I ensure that the user claiming ownership of the email actually owns it?*" This may sound pedantic, but it's important to be very precise when speaking to security concepts. The presence of an email address in a JWT **does not** necessarily indicate a user's "*ownership*" of that email address and should not be relied upon for such a purpose.

Comment: That being said, you may benefit from reading some more fundamental literature on how signed JWTs work in practice. In short, there will generally be a cryptographically-signed "signature" included with the JWT itself. This signature is created with a private key that only the provider themselves has access to. The signature can then be algorithmically bumped up against public keys contained in Google's publicly-accessible certificates to verify that Google did indeed sign the token with its private key. If the plaintext content of the JWT changes, **the signature would no longer be valid.**

Comment: [jwt.io has a good, very brief primer to how JWT signatures work in practice on their Introduction page](https://jwt.io/introduction#Signature).

Comment: @esqew Thank you I understand that the email field in the JWT does not by itself say anything about whether the user owns that particular email.
But I am wondering since I am using google's verification method that it then means that the claimed email is actually the email of the sender after verification success.
like so in .net:
var verifiedPayload = GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(JWT_credentials)

Does GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync send a request to google's api to bump the signature up against the public keys?

Comment: "*Does GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync send a request to google's api to bump the signature up against the public keys?*" It does - the library itself uses a certificate cache that's pulled from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs periodically. But don't take my word for it - [the source code of the library you're using, which is freely available on GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/01f70c7395800cb593b9dcecb163aa0027d00ef8/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/SignedTokenVerification.cs#L49). Reading it yourself can answer all the questions you've posed.

Comment: Additionally, [the documentation for the `ValidateAsync()` method you reference](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Apis/latest/Google.Apis.Auth.GoogleJsonWebSignature#Google_Apis_Auth_GoogleJsonWebSignature_ValidateAsync_System_String_Google_Apis_Auth_GoogleJsonWebSignature_ValidationSettings_) also explicitly mentions: "*Google certificates are cached, and refreshed once per hour.*"

Comment: "*I am wondering since I am using google's verification method that it then means that the claimed email is actually the email of the sender after verification success.*" Again, it's *extremely* important to note that verifying the JWT ***only*** verifies that the contents of the JWT have been signed by the identity authority's private key as they have been presented to your server. It **does not** mean that the user presenting that JWT is the user for whom the token was initially generated - JWTs can be stolen by and misused similar to any other authentication scheme's secrets.

Comment: @esqew thank you again, I appreciate the links to the source code of the verification, this eases my mind as I know understand that there indeed is a server to server validation happening. And yes I understand that the authentication token can be stolen and thus u can never be 100% certain that the user is who they claim to be. 
I appreciate the help as it was hard for me to google this as I was given generic and superficial google search results about the verification process of JWT tokens.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the method: `GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync` of google's .net client ultimately handles the verification of the JWT via a [server to server transaction.](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/01f70c7395800cb593b9dcecb163aa0027d00ef8/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/GoogleJsonWebSignature.cs#L57)

Thus I can count on the user being who they claim to be after having verified the JWT.

```js
GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload googleUser;

try {
    googleUser = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(data.Credential);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return TypedResults.Problem(statusCode: StatusCodes.Status404NotFound);
}

if (googleUser.Email == "allowed@email.com") {
    // Authenticate user
}
```

While of course, as with any other form of authentication, being aware of the possiblity that the user's Google account may have been hacked.

I had read somewhere that a JWT token was a self enclosed system, and that it can validate itself, which may technically still be true but threw me off and made me think there wasnt a server to server verification happening.